# When making a finite field from an irreducible polynomial, is the degree the only relevant property?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

For example, consider $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$. Both $(x^3+x+1)$ and $(x^3+x^2+1)$ are maximal, since both polynomials are irreducible (degree is 3, and there are no roots). Then we know the fields $\mathbb{F}_2[x] / (x^3+x+1)$ and $\mathbb{F}_2[x] / (x^3+x^2+1)$ are fields order 8, since the basis is $\{1, \theta,\theta^2\}$. But are the two fields isomorphic?

My guess is that they are not, since in $\mathbb{F}_2[x] / (x^3+x+1)$, 
 $\theta^3=\theta+1$, whereas in $\mathbb{F}_2[x] / (x^3+x^2+1)$, 
 $\theta^3=\theta^2+1$.

Comment: Consider $F_2[x]$ polynomial ring with polynomial $x^7-1=0$'s splitting field. Check $(x^3+x+1)(x^3+x^2+1)(x-1)=x^7-1$ over $F_2[x]$. So splitting field of $x^7-1$ over $F_2$ contains those 2 fields but cardinality shows that they are the same in the same ambient field(i.e. splitting field of $x^7-1$).

Comment: In short, yes, the two fields are isomorphic. I recommend you try to find an isomorphism. Remember, you have written the same symbol, $\theta$, for two very different entities.

Comment: Maybe I should've written $\theta_1, \theta_2$.

Comment: I suggest to see Example 2.3 from [this valuable book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387952734) to understand this subject.

Comment: Would it be illegal if I ask what the example is?

Comment: In fact, because the two cubic polynomials are each others reciprocals, you will see that $1/\theta_1$ can play the role of $\theta_2$.